# Specific alignment within \begin{align} environment

Tags: align

I would like to produce the following alignment with `\begin{align*}...\end{align*}`.

```
   -0,1 <  E  < 0,1 
    6,3 <  S  < 6,4 
6,3-0,1 < S+E < 6,4+0,1
    6,2 <  I  < 6,5
```

I can't figure out where to place the `&` signs. 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `array`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2} % like in cases
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt} % use math spacings
\begin{array}{ r<{{}} c >{{}}l }
   -0{,}1   < &  E  & < 0{,}1 \\
    6{,}3   < &  S  & < 6{,}4 \\
6{,}3-0{,}1 < & S+E & < 6{,}4+0{,}1 \\
    6{,}2   < &  I  & < 6{,}5
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}



alignat:
\begin{alignat}{2}
   -0,1 &< E &&< 0,1 \\
    6,3 &< S &&< 6,4 \\
6,3-0,1 &<S+E&&< 6,4+0,1 \\
   -0,1 &< I &&< 6,5  
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm curious: why does it need `&&`?

Comment: @muxoveji all ams alignments alternate between  right and left alignment as if `\begin{array}{rlrlrlrlrlrlrlrlrlrl}` and you have no new entries to the left of the second `<` so that column is empty.  (put `x` in between the `&` to see what I mean.)

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks a lot for the explanation!

Answer (score 5):

`align` family environments, by nature, produce right/left alignments of successive columns.  Thus they are not easily adapted to achieve the center-alignment of the middle column that was requested.

Also, in order to not treat the comma as punctuation, one can either enclose each comma in its own braces `{,}` (yuck!), or use the `\cmac` macro provided to use active commas to fix the problem...Just make sure you don't use commas in another context while `\cmac` is active.

With `tabstackengine`...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\let\svcm,
{
\catcode`,=\active %
\gdef,{{\svcm}}
}
\newcommand\cmac{\catcode`,=\active }
\TABstackMath
\begin{document}
\[
  \TABbinary
  \cmac
  \setstacktabulargap{0pt}
  \tabularCenterstack{rcl}{
   -0,1 <& E &< 0,1 \\
    6,3 <& S &< 6,4 \\
6,3-0,1 <&S+E&< 6,4+0,1 \\
    6,2 <& I &< 6,5}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one wants more vertical spacing between the lines, simply add `\setstackgap{L}{1.2\baselineskip}` to the mix:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another solution with the `eqparbox` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand{\eqmathbox}[2][M]{\eqmakebox[#1]{$\displaystyle#2$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
   -0{,}1 &< \eqmathbox{E} < 0{,}1 \\
    6{,}3 &< \eqmathbox{S} < 6{,}4 \\
6{,}3-0{,}1 & <\eqmathbox{S+E} < 6{,}4+0{,}1 \\
    6{,}2 & < \eqmathbox{I} < 6{,}5
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]